# Rails 3.2: Devise: Email Name

Tags: email, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2 application which uses Devise for authentication.

I would like the confirmation email for signups to have "Foo Signups" as the from: email name and "signups@foo.com" as the email address. Right now, I just have "signups@foo.com" as the from: email address.

My config looks like this:

```
# in the file config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender="signups@foo.com"

# etc...
```

and

```
# in the file config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_ADDRESS"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

where GMAIL_ADDRESS and GMAIL_PASSWORD are my Gmail user and password as environment variables and different from signups@foo.com.

How do I configure SMTP or Devise to make "Foo Signups" as the email name and "signups@foo.com" as the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ActionMailer you can set your from email address similar to `"#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>"`

I have not tried this in Devise, but I would think the same thought process would work for the config since I am sure it is just sending that info along to ActionMailer:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender= "Foo Signups <signups@foo.com>"
  #...
end
```